# Convert Date Format to String Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file to get data from ajax. Then I made the ajax to put the result into html using jquery. My problem is, there's a data from my db that have date format. When I want to put it to html, it doesn't works.

Here's my code:

```
function getKonsumen()
    {
        var selname = $("select[name=konsumen]").val();
            $.ajax({ url: "getData.php",
                data: {"selname":selname},
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(output) {
                  console.log(output);
                    $("#namak").val(output[2]);
                    $("#ktpk").val(output[3]);
                    $("#emailk").val(output[4]);
                    $("#hpk").val(output[5]);
                    $("#alamatk").val(output[6]);
                    $("#kotak").val(output[7]);
                    var newd = new Date(output[8]);
                    $("#bdayk").val(newd.toString());
                }

            });
    }
```

my sample of output[8] is like '2015-08-01' or '2014-12-25'
all my form has been filled by this function, except the bdayk. Any solution?

Comment: So you have a string. Convert it to Date. Then convert it to string. Why not $("#bdayk").val(output[8]);

Comment: No, it's not a string. I got the data from mysql which type is Date. then I want to display it to textbox. It doesn't display anything, so I try to convert it to text/string, but still nothing happened

Comment: What is the result of console.log(output)? And what console.log(typeof output[8]) is resulting?

Comment: Its result is 2015-12-01 for example

Comment: Nevermind, already find my solution.... thanks for reply

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: Okay i see it now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

Convert my date data from sql to string using php, then I throw to javascript. it's all done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following syntax -

`new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ]);`

So in your case it should be

`var newd = new Date(2015,07,1);`

And do note that months in Javascript start from 0 rather than 1.

Comment: Already try to split data what I get from mysql. But still it doesn't show anything on my textbox